# "No module named appengine.base" error after deploying Django app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to deploy a Django application to Google App Engine. The app deploys successfully, but throws the following error when I try to access it in a web browser:

```
<class 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured'>: 'appengine' isn't an available database backend. Available options are: 'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named appengine.base
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/test.350631415612260549/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    InstallAppengineHelperForDjango()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/test.350631415612260549/appengine_django/__init__.py", line 545, in InstallAppengineHelperForDjango
    InstallDjangoModuleReplacements()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/test.350631415612260549/appengine_django/__init__.py", line 262, in InstallDjangoModuleReplacements
    import django.db
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/test.350631415612260549/django/db/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(settings.DATABASE_ENGINE)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/test.350631415612260549/django/db/__init__.py", line 37, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

Additional information: I'm not the original developer of the app, nor am I very familiar with Google App Engine.

My workflow is as follows: pull the code from a Git repository, configure it as a new app in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher GUI (for Mac OS X), then deploy. Am I missing any steps, such as configuring backend settings locally before deploying?

Comment: This definitely is a problem with the configuration (settings) of your project. Can you give some more details how django is used in this app engine project? Is it using django-appengine (also known as django-nonrel) or native app engine support?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the project is using native app engine support, but my ignorance of GAE isn't helping -- are there any telltale signs that would point to either native app engine or django-appengine use? Searching the source code reveals no matches for either "django-appengine" or "django-nonrel", but I do see a directory named "appengine_django" in the project root.

Comment: Hm, ok, that doesn't help much. Let me ask it like this: are you deploying with `appcfg.py` or via `manage.py remote` or are you using the launcher to deploy (never used it, so I don't know this is possible). In any case, if would be a good idea to open `settings.py` file from your project folder and configure `DATABASE_ENGINE` or `DATABASES['ENGINE']` setting to be an empty string `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have appengine_django in your project root you are using [App Engine Helper](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/). You might have some import path problems so you can try upgrading to the latest version of the helper. However, it is a deprecated project and you are better off porting to [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) if possible. Part of the migration will be changing your database engine in settings.py from 'appengine' (causing your error) to 'dbindexer'